# HTML video tag different background-color on different machines

Tags: html, css, vue.js, browser, background-color

I have web App where a video is being played, the video and the web page have being set to the same background color however the video background appears different on different machines same browser. What I want to achieve is to have a video of a spinning triangle on a grey background color similar to the web page background color.This what I get on different machines instead [from hp Probook 445 G7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUmmT.png) [from hp elitbook 8470](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyJnU.png). The images are from the same web App but the firsr image has a darker video background unlike the second one. What could be the cause and how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to solve a similar issue without success.

Went as far as saving out a transparent background in video which did not turn out to be a viable solution.

My thought is the white balance on your computers change the light gray/white color values slightly.

I've also noticed the exact same hex or color values exporting slightly different in video than with svg or png backgrounds. I've battled that by using a gradient of a background to soften the edges so it appears seamless.